# Need advise on the Batch Script with the output:

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Need your expert advice on the below:

Here is the code:

Note: serial is set to value of 100 which is default and it is pulled from the another script where all the server details are stored.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET serverlist=
SET env=TBD

if /I "%2" EQU "D"  (set env=dev&& set env_dir=dev)
if /I "%2" EQU "U"  (set env=uat&& set env_dir=uat)
if /I "%2" EQU "P"  (set env=prod&& set env_dir=prod)


echo Here are the server details for %env% %1:

echo These are for DEV:
FOR /l %%a IN (1,1,50) DO (if defined %env%_%serial%_DEVser_%%a_ (for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims==, " %%a in ('set %env%_%serial%_DEVser_%%a_') do (if %%c NEQ dup (echo %%a ^(%%b^,%%c^) & set serverdetails=!serverdetails! %%a %%b %%c) )))


echo These are for UAT:
FOR /l %%a IN (1,1,50) DO (if defined %env%_%serial%_UATser_%%a_ (for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims==, " %%a in ('set %env%_%serial%_UATser_%%a_') do (if %%c NEQ dup (echo %%a ^(%%b^,%%c^) & set serverdetails=!serverdetails! %%a %%b %%c) )))

echo These are for PROD:
FOR /l %%a IN (1,1,50) DO (if defined %env%_%serial%_PRODser_%%a_ (for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims==, " %%a in ('set %env%_%serial%_PRODser_%%a_') do (if %%c NEQ dup (echo %%a ^(%%b^,%%c^) & set serverdetails=!serverdetails! %%a %%b %%c) )))


echo details of all the server: 
echo %serverdetails%
```

Current output:

```
These are for DEV:
D00123 (testing1)
D00456 (testing2)
D00789 (testing3)

These are for UAT:
UAT001 (UAT-env1)
UAT002 (UAT-env2)
UAT003 (UAT-env3)

These are for PROD:
PRD001 (PRD-env1)
PRD002 (PRD-env2)
PRD003 (PRD-env3)

details of all the server: 
D00123 testing1     D00456 testing2     D00789 testing3     UAT001 UAT-env1     UAT002 UAT-env2     UAT003 UAT-env3     PRD001 PRD-env1     PRD002 PRD-env2     PRD003 PRD-env3
```

Question:

1. For the details of all the server output: I would like to get the output below

```
    D00123
    D00456
    D00789
    UAT001
    UAT002
    UAT003
    PRD001
    PRD002
    PRD003
```

2. If the Dev server details are requested, then UAT / PROD details should not be visible
   similarly, if PROD is requested, then DEV and UAT should not be visible.

can you please help me with this?

Comment: I believe we have a case of over-cropping. We have no idea of what `serial` is set to, nor which `%env%_%serial%_DEVser_%%a_` might be set or what their values might be. `env_dir` appears to have no purpose. `echo %%a ^(%%b^,%%c^)` should report `something (athing,anotherthing)` which doesn't appear in the reported output & the (edited) format seems incorrect as `details ... server` should be a single line given the code shown. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Magoo you are right!!! I have updated my questions with all the details. Please see if it makes sense and how to get the desired output. Kindly help me

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:: Dummy data established outside of routine

SET "serial=100"
SET "ser_=xyz"

SET "dev_%serial%_dev%ser_%1_=D00123 something1,testing1"
SET "dev_%serial%_dev%ser_%16_=D00456 something2,testing2"
SET "dev_%serial%_dev%ser_%22_=D00789 something3,testing3"
SET "dev_%serial%_dev%ser_%35_=D00987 something4,dup"

SET "uat_%serial%_uat%ser_%1_=UAT123 something11,testing4"
SET "uat_%serial%_uat%ser_%16_=UAT456 something12,testing5"
SET "uat_%serial%_uat%ser_%22_=UAT789 something13,dup"
SET "uat_%serial%_uat%ser_%35_=UAT987 something14,testing7"

SET "prod_%serial%_prod%ser_%1_=PRD123 something21,dup"
SET "prod_%serial%_prod%ser_%16_=PRD456 something22,testing9"
SET "prod_%serial%_prod%ser_%22_=PRD789 something23,testing10"
SET "prod_%serial%_prod%ser_%35_=PRD987 something24,testing11"

SET |FIND /i "something"

IF /i "%1"=="d" SET "env=dev"
IF /i "%1"=="u" SET "env=uat"
IF /i "%1"=="p" SET "env=prod"

for %%e in (dev uat prod) do (
 SET "report="
 if /i "%%e"=="%env%" SET "report=Y"
 IF DEFINED report echo These are for %env%:
 FOR /l %%o IN (1,1,50) DO if defined %%e_%serial%_%%e%ser_%%%o_ (
  for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims==, " %%u in (
   'set %%e_%serial%_%%e%ser_%%%o_'
  ) do if %%w NEQ dup set "%%eserverdetails=!%%eserverdetails! %%u"&IF DEFINED report echo %%u
 )
 SET "serverdetails=!serverdetails! !%%eserverdetails!"
)

echo These are for ALL:
FOR %%e IN (%serverdetails%) DO ECHO %%e

GOTO :EOF
```

Still not really clear on the values in the variables. Test setup shown. Routine accepts `d`, `u` or `p` as first param.

Don't know what `ser_` is set to.

Your code contains `for..%%a` within a `for..%%a` - decidedly not good practice.

Speaking of which, a couple of proved "good practice" principles:

Use `set "var=value"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign `"` or a terminal backslash or Space. Build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier. If the syntax `set var="value"` is used, then the quotes become part of the value assigned.

Prefer to avoid ADFNPSTXZ (in either case) as metavariables (loop-control variables) ADFNPSTXZ are also metavariable-modifiers which can lead to difficult-to-find bugs (See `for/f` from the prompt for documentation)

So...

Having established `env`, process the variables for each of the three possibilities (in `%%e`). Filter the values for `%%e _ %serial% _ %%e %ser_% %%o _` where `%%o` is 1..50 and append to `%%eserverdetails` if the third token of the variable is not `dup`. If `%%e` matches `%env%` then set the `report` flag which controls whether the data is `echo`ed.

Finally, list the `serverdetails` data.

Of course, it would also be possible to list `!%env%serverdetails!` for the individual lists, which would make the `report` flag and reporting the data within the `%%u` loop redundant.

Append each `%%eserverdetails` to `serverdetails` after each `%%e` is processed